# How to compile Squid 5.6 for Debian 11

Tags: debian, compile, squid

I need compile Squid 5.6 or 5.5 for Debian 11. I have a squid 4 non transparent proxy over Debian 11 with *ncsa_auth*, but the problem is that squid version can´t manage websockets (ws and wss connections).